# Swift adoption of Objective-C protocol breaks complicated structure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a subproject which has a class and respective delegate protocol declared in Objective-C. When I adopt the protocol in my Swift class, my framework compiles fine.

When I try to compile the parent project, which uses the framework's code, I am flooded with warnings and errors. The warnings mostly pertain to many duplicate redefinitions of extensions in the subproject, and missing nullability keywords.

The compile errors are:

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'xxx': '/Users/.../Other Sources/xxx-Bridging-Header.h'
>
> Could not build module 'xxx'
>
> Failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/.../DerivedData/yyy-chcdnxtdlbcyuubqtvpncdocmjor/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/yyy-iPhone-Bridging-Header-swift_2328JD7S5BITU-clang_3QCMQH6DYOKXP.pch' for bridging header '/Users/.../yyy-iPhone-Bridging-Header.h'

All errors and warnings disappear as soon as I remove the adoption of the protocol. I cannot figure out any reason why this is happening, I have quite a bit of Swift intertwined in our Objective-C projects and I've never seen this before.

Any ideas or similar experiences?